# CSS Web fonts do not expand DIV when font-size increased?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

You can see what I have here with the large fonts in the thumbnails: http://unlockinglg.com/beta/index.html

I am using font-awesome with bootstrap

[image]

Comment: Could be related to height of the i element inherited from bootstrap. Checking it out now.

Comment: Dude!  That video about goanimate is awesome!

Comment: @Phillip haha, but it's not mine. It's just a filler :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of `bootstrap.min.css` is responsible:

```
[class^="icon-"],[class*=" icon-"]{height:14px}
```

A quick (read: dirty) fix would be to add the following to your custom stylesheet:

```
[class^="icon-"],[class*=" icon-"]{height:auto !important}
```